# How do I get to the 8 Bit Realm?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

According to the wiki, I get there through the inexplicable door in the Distant Woods. I need to go there to farm pixels for a key.

Problem is, I go to the Distant Woods, and I don't see that door.

How am I supposed to get to the 8-bit realm?

Comment: you have to wear the gadget that the mystic guy gives you

Comment: Which one is that? (I have a huge amount of stuff in my inventory now, and I suspect that was forever ago, so I have no idea what I need to equip.)

Comment: the _Continuum transfunctioner_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talk to the Crackpot Mystic, and he will give you an accessory (the [continuum transfunctioner](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Continuum_transfunctioner)) to wear. While you have that accessory equippped, the Inexplicable Door will be visible in the bottom right of the Distant Woods.

Comment: Oh boy, that means I gotta hunt through my inventory, because I probably already have it....

Comment: It's round, if that helps :P